# Why is tailwind not working with react + webpack peoject?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss

I installed `tailwind` using [the official guide with PostCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

**My React and webpack project file structure**

```
 |--src
     |--components
         |--pages
             |--Details.js
         |--App.js
         |--NavBar.js
         |--About.js
         |--index.js
 |--static
     |--css
         |--index.css
     |--frontend
         |--main.js
     |--images
 |--templates
     |--frontend
         |--index.html
 |--postcss.config.js
 |--tailwind.config.js
 |--webpack.config.js
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}",
"./src/components/pages/*.{html,js}",
"./src/components/*.{html,js}",
"./static/frontend/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
}
};
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Tailwind CDN works fine

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Do you get any errors? Have you checked developer console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postcss.config.js

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["postcss-preset-env", tailwindcss],
};
```

you need to install

```
npm i postcss-preset-env
```

Also `tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately, should i re-create the entire project?

Comment: did u restart the server after change?

Comment: `npm i postcss-preset-env`

Comment: nothing same problem

Comment: change the `tailwind.config.js` to the code that I pasted

Answer (score 0):

you should change import style to

```
@import "tailwindcss/base.css";
@import "tailwindcss/components.css";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities.css";
```